# jQuery - Multiple links and multiple classes. Toggle on/off

Tags: jquery, class, hyperlink

I had this one problem yesterday and both solutions are here at the js section http://jsfiddle.net/6jm2s/22/

But now i have same problem ...except the classes that need to be removed are all different.

This should explain what i want... http://jsfiddle.net/YeWna/7/

Any thoughts?

**Solution demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YeWna/16/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var klasses = $.map($(".links a"), function(elt) {
    return $(elt).attr("class");
}).join(" ");
$(".links a").click(function(){
    var link = $(this),
        aBox = $(".aBox"),
        klass = link.attr("class");
    aBox.hasClass(klass) ? aBox.removeClass(klass) : aBox.removeClass(klasses).addClass(klass);

    return false;
})
```

Try that (updated)

Comment: @Robin now im not able to toggle off class from the .aBox by clicking the same link again and thats more or less the idea. http://jsfiddle.net/YeWna/8/

Comment: @Robin it would seem like your edited js does the same thing as the previous one? http://jsfiddle.net/YeWna/9/

Comment: @Robin that seems to do the trick. Thanks man... this will help alot.

Comment: @Robin Just a question out of curiosity. Why (klass) ? why not like.. (class) ?

Comment: Sometimes, class is a reserved keyword, so I just made a habit of naming variables klass... You don't have to do the same ;)

Comment: @Robin it seems like i jumped the gun on this one... i failed to mention that .aBox would have other classes as well and what this code does is basically get rid of all those extra classes... i added two extra classes there that disappear from .aBox when any of the links are clicked .test-one has yellow outline and .test-two has pink border and they both disappear http://jsfiddle.net/YeWna/15/

Oh and just adding .test-one and .test-two afterwards isnt an option.. all the classes at .aBox should stay intact...  :/

Comment: @Robin Alright that worked.. i also checked my actual code to make sure there arent any loose ends.. Worked great. Thanks!